# Pasting a smaller number of columns than selected duplicates data

Tags: handsontable

I tried to search for a similar question but did not find it - I think it may be out there and any help is appreciated.

I have a simple `handsontable` implementation - the issue only appears when you copy a certain number of columns from excel, 2 for example, and the paste into `handsontable` where a larger number of columns has been selected (say 10).

It happens even in standard `handsontable` examples such as the example pasted here.

All I did was select all the records, delete them and then select an entire row and pasted two columns. As you can see the data was duplicated for the following columns [sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY381.png).

Has anyone seen this before?

Is there a solution I am obviously missing?

Comment: Try posting your `jsfiddle` link instead of a link to an image.

Comment: here ya go http://jsfiddle.net/dkyhgav9/ - it is the standard handsontable example